# Taskbar Icon for New Mail

Tags: macos, email, notifications, exchange

I'm running Mac OS X 10.9.1 using the Mail app (v7.1) to interact with my exchange email account.

Is there any way to configure the Mail app to show an icon in the task bar whenever I have new mail?

I have the pop up notifications and the red number in my hidden dock and alt-tab screens, however, I would really like to just have a non-intrusive little black mail icon on the task bar when I have unread mail. This is default on Windows with Outlook, I just haven't found any Mac apps that will replicate it yet.

Any ideas, suggestions, tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible solely with OS X and Mail.

However, third-party apps such as [**Mail Unread Menu**](http://loganrockmore.com/mailunreadmenu/) can add an icon to the menu bar.

[image]

Comment: This does no longer work in Mavericks.